# ARRAYFORMULA VLOOKUP with ISBLANK in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get a `VLOOKUP` to work on an entire column (minus the header), but I want blank entries if the column I am searching for is empty. I tried both these formulas, but to no avail (I still get the N/A in empty cells):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP(O2:O,Sheet1!B:C,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(O2:O,Sheet1!B:C,2,FALSE)))
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(O2:O<>"",VLOOKUP(O2:O,Sheet1!B:C,2,FALSE)),"")
```

This is a slightly more complicated way than what I got working in another part of my sheet, which is the same without the VLOOKUP:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(J2:J),"",J2:J))
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is wrong with the formulas you tried?

Comment: still leaves '#N/A' values in the empty cells instead of empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to leave a blank instead of `#N/A` in a cell, you can use `=IFERROR`.

Like this:

```
=IFERROR(Your_formula, "value if the formula returns an error")
```

Since you are using `ARRAYFORMULA`, the iferror must be inside it

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(O2:O,Sheet1!B:C,2,FALSE),""))
```